# Accessing <a> inside div id

Tags: jquery

im trying to color the `<a>` background color

```
<div id="contact"><a href="mailto:name@.domain.net>name</a>
```

with the selector

```
$('#contact a').css("background", "red");
```

however im not successfull, where is my error?

Comment: Probably just a typo, but you're missing a closing quote mark on your `href` attribute in the `a` element.

Comment: Can you post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example demonstrating your problem? Because it works for me.

Comment: Is the code failing in all browsers or just certain ones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are missing a double quotes in the end of href

see demo http://jsfiddle.net/URJPV/1/

Answer (score -3):

try this one:

```
<a id="contact_link" href="mailto:name@.domain.net>name</a>

$('a#contact_link').css("background", "red");
```